# Jersey: Best practice handling restful HTTP PUT (update) request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, put, pojo

Suppose I have very simple `User` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password", "created", "lastModified"})
public class User {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String password
    public Long created;
    public Long lastModified;
}
```

When we serialize a `User` entity to JSON string, we filter out `password`, `created` and `lastModified`. And then user at the front end will update the user's name and put the user back to our Restful service.

And my pseudo controller method handling the `PUT` request:

```
@Path("/user/{id}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void saveUpdate(@PathParam("id")String id, User user) {
    userService.save(user);
}
```

In the above method I expect Jackson will deserialize the JSON string sent by front end to the POJO `user` instance, and then call our service to save the instance.

So far everything looks cool. However the concern raised when we pass the `user` POJO to `userService` to save it. Remember we have three properties ignored when we serizalize the `user` into JSON: `password`, `created`, `lastModified`, and we have to get the value of those missing properties from database and then merge with the data sent through from front end.

Doing the merge operation is a very simple but tedious task for coder. I was wondering if there is any good practices to handle this case in an easy and elegant way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose User object is entity object that is going to be saved into DB so Best practice is not to expose entity objects to FE but use DTO objects that contains only fields that FE needs to know about (consider to hide id aswell and use UUID instead as id values are predictable). Later you can map such DTO object to Entity by using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) so you can easily merge between userDTO and user entity objects and then just persist entity without worrying about state of missing fields

Moreover nowdays many web services disabling PUT requests for their applications and uses POST instead. I don't familiar much with reason why but that was one of the security issues when we passed out application to security checks

Comment: by `id` I mean generic ID used, could be UUID, or any other ID used in the underline system; DTO is not something I am in fond of. The lesser code the better; Can you point out a link to a **good** example using `ObjectMapper`? `PUT` is not encouraged because many firewall block it. You can still use `PUT` but fake it through `POST` with `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header set to `PUT`

Comment: Actually `PUT` is not proper in the case because by semantic it is suppose to update a specific attribute of the `User` entity, not the entire entity. I change it to `POST` in the question

Comment: I just quickly google `ObjectMapper` and found it's not something help you map `DTO` to Entity. In fact it converts your Java object to/from JSON string.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny. I appreciate the `ModelMapper` and I give you a up, looks nice. However I am not with the DTO approach, it duplicates too many code

Comment: You can use entity classes with @JsonIgnore annotation on fields you don't want to expose to client

Comment: The question is not about serialization, but de-serialization and merge if you read the question carefully

Comment: so ModelMapper should to the trick. Just retrieve the entity from DB and merge with one you got from FE

Answer (score 1):

I think the concern is more about your service instead of the REST API. I mean, if user's 3 properties "password", "created" and "lastModified" shouldn't be visible to the presentation layer, then the service should be able to handle saving without them.

In the persistent layer, you can definitely update `User` without all properties populated. Or a better design, let's separate UserLogin("id", "password", "created", "lastModified") and User("id", "name") which point to the same DB table. Then an update on User doesn't need other unnecessary properties at all.

Comment: UserLogin approach looks nice. However the things is "created", "lastModified" and maybe some other fields are common across all model classes, meaning I need to define a separate DTO class for all model classes to apply the approach. This doesn't look really DRY...

Comment: Got your point. Such auditing infos, like `created` or `lastModified`, are common between all domain objects. So, normally, I would create a base object for those properties, e.g. `AuditableEntity(created, lastModified, createdUser, lastModifiedUser)`. And these base properties will be handled by a centre point instead of duplicating across all services, e.g Hibernate listener https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html. I think we reach S (single responsibility) and D (DRY).

Comment: I have a generic way to handle `created` and `lastModified` already. The question is if I use `DTO` like `UserLogin` as you mentioned above, I can easily merge the update data into the model entity but I need to created a separate `DTO` class for each model class, which is not DRY. If I don't create `DTO`, I am facing to problem of merging `null` value on common properties like `created` and `lastModified` into entity before saving to database. `lastModified` might be easier because we will update it anyway, but for other things like `created` is not that simple